# How to Pass MethodName as Parameter of a Procedure in VBNET

Tags: vb.net, function, methods, parameter-passing

I want to create a Procedure that its parameter is also a procedure. Is it possible?

 I created some procedures to be used as parameters below:

```
Private Sub Jump(xStr as string)
    Msgbox xStr & " is jumping."
End Sub

Private Sub Run(xStr as string)
    Msgbox xStr & " is jumping."
End Sub
```

this procedure should call the procedure above:

```
Private Sub ExecuteProcedure(?, StringParameter) '- i do not know what to put in there
     ? ' - name of the procedure with parameter
End Sub
```

usage:

```
 ExecuteProcedure(Jump, "StringName")
 ExecuteProcedure(Run, "StringName")
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the following code is an example for what you need.

```
Public Delegate Sub TestDelegate(ByVal result As TestResult)

Private Sub RunTest(ByVal testFunction As TestDelegate)

     Dim result As New TestResult
     result.startTime = DateTime.Now
     testFunction(result)
     result.endTime = DateTime.Now

End Sub

Private Sub MenuItemStartTests_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItemStartTests.Click

     Debug.WriteLine("Starting Tests...")
     Debug.WriteLine("")
     '==================================
     ' Add Calls to Test Modules Here

     RunTest(AddressOf Test1)
     RunTest(AddressOf Test2)

     '==================================

     Debug.WriteLine("")
     Debug.WriteLine("Tests Completed")

End Sub
```

The entire article can be found at http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2007/07/passing-function-by-reference-in-vbnet.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 because it's generally the task of third-parties to cast votes rather than the OP and I'm a third-party.

Comment: what is testresult?