# How to define a function as a parameter in another function in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, root, numerical-methods

I want to creat a VB Code for brent method (a numerical method) which can takes an analytic function and find the root.  How can I do this in VB 2010? the function Brent method takes is like:

```
Function W_Bazin_Rect_h(ByVal Q As Double,
            ByVal w As Double,
            ByVal a As Double,
            ByVal S As Double) As Double
Dim tempstr As String
If w < 0 Or a <= 0 Then
    tempstr = "Error on input"
    ShowMessageBox(tempstr)
    Exit Function
End If

If Q <= 0 Then
    Return 0
End If
g = 9.81
u = (0.405 + 0.003 / h) * (1 + 0.55 * (h / (h + a)) ^ 2)
Q = ((2 * g) ^ 0.5 * u * w * h ^ (3 / 2)) * (1 - (S / h) ^ 1.5) ^ 0.385

End Function
```

Should i define brent methode as a class or a function?

I want to initialize the function (i.e Q=1,a=1,w=1,S=1) and then pass the function to the Brent method which could return the value of h.
What is the best way to do this in VB.NET? I want to make a general Brent method where I can pass any single valued function and find roots.

I have just started using VB, and from what I have found so far it seems like the tools you have is - to us a delegate for the function - to use a lambda expression for the function - send a pointer/adressOf - to create a function class/structure and submit this to the function

As for now I am most inclined to create a function-class. But I am not really sure how. F.ex. I make different classes for each "uniqe function" I want to integrate, but how can I pass them to the integration function when I need to specify the argument type in the integration-function-call?

This seems like a basic problem which applies to many Math operations, so I think it would be very useful to clarify this.

Comment: Mybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697504/how-to-pass-methodname-as-parameter-of-a-procedure-in-vbnet.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't show the error message in the function. I would return something like [Double.NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx), that way you seperate the UI from the logic.

By looking at what you have, you could create something like the [Math class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx). Having your function as shared in a class that could be called MathFunction or something.

Also, you forgot to return a value.